# What I can check using MockMvc in method which gets @ModelAttribute as parameter of this method?

Tags: java, testing, spring-mvc, mocking

I have a method method located in class marked as @Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEvent(Model model,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("myEvent") Event event,
            BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            @RequestParam(required = true) Integer selectedEventTypeId,
            @RequestParam(required = true) Integer selectedEventStatusId) {

        if (result.getErrorCount() > 1 ){
            return "eventDetailsAdd";
        }
        eventService.addEvent(event, selectedEventTypeId, selectedEventStatusId);
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("idEvent", event.getId());
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("message", "added correctly at " + new Date() );
        return "redirect:eventDetails";
    }
```

Using MockMvc what can I check?

**UPDATE**

If I write following code:

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/addEvent");
        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(request);

        result.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
```

I see:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<405>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$5.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:549)
    ...
```

**UPDATE**

I copy your example:

```
public class ModelAssertionTests {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Before
        public void setup() {

                SampleController controller = new SampleController("a string value", 3, new Person("a name"));

                this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
                                .defaultRequest(get("/"))
                                .alwaysExpect(status().isOk())
                                .build();
        }


        @Test
        public void testHasErrors() throws Exception {
                mockMvc.perform(post("/persons")).andExpect(model().attributeHasErrors("person"));
        }




        @Controller
        private static class SampleController {

                private final Object[] values;

                public SampleController(Object... values) {
                        this.values = values;
                }

                @RequestMapping("/")
                public String handle(Model model) {
                        for (Object value : this.values) {
                                model.addAttribute(value);
                        }
                        return "view";
                }

                @RequestMapping(value="/persons", method=RequestMethod.POST)
                public String create(@Valid Person person, BindingResult result, Model model) {
                        return "view";
                }
        }

}
class Person{
    public Person(){}
    public Person(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

After this code execution I see next trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No errors for attribute [person]
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:39)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ModelResultMatchers$5.match(ModelResultMatchers.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:141)
    at com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.ModelAssertionTests.testHasErrors(ModelAssertionTests.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I am so confused

Answer (score 1):

MockMvc will let you check various conditions about the received response. You can find some information at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework

In particular you might be interested in the following class: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html

This class let you access additional result matchers that you can use for asserting conditions on the status, content, headers, model, view, etc.

In your case you could check if:

- status is 200 OK or if it is a redirect together with the redirect url
- the correct view has been rendered (in case of errors count higher than 1)
- event has errors

Comment: If you follow the first link you will find a few examples that should help you start. Also you can go to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-test-mvc/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/samples/standalone and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc for more code examples. They are pretty straightforward.

Comment: thx. I understood how check first two conditions from you list. But I ask you show "event has errors" example

Comment: Mateusz Mrozewski, you have not ideas?

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test-mvc/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/samples/standalone/resultmatchers/ModelAssertionTests.java and lines 91 and 96.

Comment: What the place where instance Person gets ?

Comment: Your test is doing a POST which is handled by create method and that method does not set the model.